# How to to control Javafx media player app by user input

Tags: java, javafx

i am new to java and javafx , i created javafx media player and it wroks fine but i tried to control pause and play functions using user input fro example if user enter 1 should perform the pause function and the video pause .
when i run my code actully nothing is happening and the application keep loading .is that possible ? any help is appreciated thanks in advance .

```
public class Main extends Application {
Player player ;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

     player =new Player("file:///C:/song.mp4");
    Scene scene =new Scene(player,720,480,Color.BLACK);



    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    primaryStage.show();
    user();
 }
public void user(){
    Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter 1 to pasue");
    int option =sc.nextInt();
    player.pause1(option);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application keeps loading because `sc.nextInt()` is waiting for user input, effectively blocking the execution. You can use another thread for that...

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(new Media("http://www.archive.org/download/moby_dick_librivox/mobydick_000_melville.mp3"));
    MediaView view = new MediaView(player);
    Pane root = new Pane(view);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Mp3 player");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    player.play();

    new Thread(() -> { 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter 1 to pasue");
        int option = sc.nextInt();
        if (option == 1) {
            player.stop();
        }
    }).start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

and it will work, but this is not a good solution either. Console applications are good for tasks that can be performed in batch mode. Your application, on the other hand, is an interactive one, so you should consider switching to event-driven programming and GUI, for example, by handling user actions with buttons